# Prove that there is a set S of 10 students containing exactly 1 person from every algebra team and exactly 1 person from every calculus team.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

60 students attend the one or both of the following courses: algebra and calculus. On algebra they are
divided into 10 teams of equal size. On calculus they are divided into different 10 teams of equal size. Prove that there is a set S of 10 students containing exactly 1 person from every algebra team and exactly 1 person from every calculus team.

I have to prove this applying concepts of graph theory, I'd appreciate if any of you could prove it.

Comment: I am slightly confused : every student attends both algebra and calculus courses, right? So each algebra team has $6$ students and each calculus team has $6$ students? If these are correct, I can probably try to solve this.

Comment: Keyphrases: System of Distinct Reprresentatives; Hall's Theorem.

Comment: Have you had a look for those phrases, JMR?

Comment: Are you still here, JMR? Numbra posted an answer two days ago – did it answer your question? It's not polite to ask for help here, and then refuse to engage with those who try to help you

Comment: I am sorry, I was studying that chapter for a test earlier and didn't really check after the test. I appreciate all the help, I will look up what you suggested and get back to you @Gerry Myerson

Comment: I think it is at least one of the course's but not necessarily both @Teresa Lisbon. I apologize for the late response.

Comment: @JMR no problem, I think there is an answer anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, indeed, see the problem as a graph problem.

Consider a bipartite graph, with vertices are $a_1, ..., a_{10}, c_1, ..., c_{10}$.
Each vertex represents a team (either a algebra or a calculus team).

Now, you put an between $a_i$ and $c_j$ if and only if there is a student who belongs to the $i$-th algebra team, and to the $j$-th calculus one.

Your graph has $60$ edges, one per student, representing the student's teams.

The problem can now be reformulated as "Does this graph admit a perfect matching ?" Indeed, you would like to pick students (=edges), such that you "cover" all the teams both in algebra and calculus (="perfect"), and you want a single student per team (=matching).

If you still need help to solve the problem, I can try to give some hints, but at least you can use some graph theory now !